Find the unittests that take "long time" using pycharm
Pycharm has the neat feature that when using the unittest tests (but also pytests) it shows the time each test takes.
In our application we have roughly ~6k unittest, most take a decent time, however some (probably a few hundred) take over 500 ms or even second+.
I wish to find these and figure out why the tests take so long.
Is that possible with pycharm (or another script), to order the tests by time taken? Or show only tests that took a certain time?

pytest has the capability of profiling test execution duration: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/usage.html#profiling-test-execution-duration
